# WordPressで投稿ページごとのお問い合わせページを設置したいです。

Tags: php, wordpress

#### 質問の背景

WordPressで、カスタム投稿(CPT UI)を使用したイベント詳細ページにお問い合わせページへの遷移ボタンを設置しております。
その際に、遷移前のイベント詳細ページごとのお問い合わせページになるように実装をしたいのですが、方法がわかりません。
お問い合わせページはContact form7の使用を検討しております。

有識者の方のお知恵をお借りできればと思っております。
よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 実装したいこと

①WordPressのカスタム投稿で、お客様が自由にイベント詳細を追加できる。（作成済）
②その際に、イベント詳細ごとにお問い合わせページを設置したい。
③お問い合わせページのデザインは同じだが、下記参考サイトのように遷移前のイベントタイトルを出力したい。
④ユーザー問い合わせ時の自動返信メール・管理者宛メールに、遷移前のイベントタイトルを出力したい。

#### 共有事項

参考サイト：
https://www.koc-japan-lp.com/seminar
こちらの「開催予定のイベント」から遷移できるそれぞれの投稿ページとお問い合わせと同じように実装したいです。

https://www.koc-japan-lp.com/seminar →
https://www.koc-japan-lp.com/event-details/cponsetsumeikai-hi13-00-21 →
https://www.koc-japan-lp.com/event-details/cponsetsumeikai-hi13-00-21/form

※cponsetsumeikai-hi13-00-21の部分は、イベント詳細ページごとに変更したいです。